# Use PostgreSQL pg_prewarm for a foreign table

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I have many foreign tables imported by `IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA`:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR myuser
   SERVER postgres
   OPTIONS ( user 'myuser', password 'mypass');
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public from server postgres INTO public;
```

I have many queries that join my local tables and foreign tables.

Q1: If I use `pg_prewarm` and the put the whole table in memory, it helps me not every time to take this table by a network.

Q2: I am worried if data changes on the foreign PostgreSQL server will be visible on my local server if the foreign table is cached.

Example: `core_category` is a foreign table

```
SELECT pg_prewarm(
    'core_category',
    -- "pre warm" pages of the last 1000 pages for 'mytable'
    first_block := (
        SELECT pg_relation_size('core_category') / current_setting('block_size')::int4 - 1000
    )
);
-- or
SELECT * FROM pg_prewarm('core_category', 'buffer');
```

Comment: I don't understand. Where is the connection between `pg_prewarm` and foreign tables?

Comment: core_category - it's foreign table. if I will put the whole table in a cache, and in the remote server it changed I use old version table?

Comment: You cannot prewarm a foreign table since its data are not in the database. The error is `ERROR:  fork "main" does not exist for this relation`. You'd have to make sure that the table is in cache on the foreign data source.

Comment: it much helped, the question is closed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`pg_prewarm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgprewarm.html) on a foreign table does not make sense: since the table is not stored in PostgreSQL, PostgreSQL cannot load it into shared buffers or the file system cache.

Indeed, an attempt to do that will result in

```
ERROR: fork "main" does not exist for this relation
```

To speed up queries involving a foreign table, you'll have to get the foreign data source to cache the data in memory.

Comment: the same applies when trying to warm up a partitioned table. Instead, try to warm up the target partition(s)